# Swift zoom in on user's location

Tags: ios, swift2, mapkit, xcode7

I am trying to figure out how to zoom in to the user's location in Swift 2.1. I have searched through the world of the internet but was unable to find a solution. Thank you to Renier Melian for helping me start this but it doesn't ask for authorization for the location and then gives an error message

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class SocialViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        self.mapView.userTrackingMode = .Follow
        self.mapView.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
    }
}

extension SocialViewController : MKMapViewDelegate{
    //Adjusting the zoom
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
        var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
        region.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.7, 0.7); //Zoom distance
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude:  userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        region.center = coordinate
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

    func mapViewWillStartLocatingUser(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
        debugPrint("startLocating")
    }
    func mapViewDidStopLocatingUser(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
        debugPrint("stopLocating")
    }
}

extension SocialViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        debugPrint("received Location")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code, changing the values of `MKCoordinateSpanMake` you can increase or reduce the zoom

add this lines on your viewDidLoad method

```
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class SocialViewController : UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    self.mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
    self.mapView.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
}
}

extension SocialViewController : MKMapViewDelegate{
    //Adjusting the zoom
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
        var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
        region.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.7, 0.7); //Zoom distance
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude:  userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        region.center = coordinate
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

    func mapViewWillStartLocatingUser(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
        debugPrint("startLocating")
    }
    func mapViewDidStopLocatingUser(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
        debugPrint("stopLocating")
    }
}

extension SocialViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
       debugPrint("received Location")
    }
```

}

Add privacy key in your info.plist

[image]

Working!!

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: When I try this it says `Cannot assign value of type 'SocialViewController' to type 'MKMapViewDelgate?'`

Comment: You made a typo when you wrote `MKMapViewDelgate` instead of `MKMapViewDelegate`

Comment: I tried it but when I built the app in the simulator, it just showed the entire USA

Comment: @salipshitz check my answer again, the location manager was missing in previous answer, there is an image showing that works, maybe you have problem with location detection in simulator you better should simulate your position, in my case I simulate NY position, best regards, happy coding

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but there is an error `2017-06-13 19:50:17.043 Paley Pain Support[7362:423280] Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146671/discussion-between-salipshitz-and-reinier-melian).

Comment: @salipshitz check my answer was updated there is the call for requestWhenInUseAuthorization in this line self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()you need also create a key in your info plist for message look at updated image to do that

Comment: It still doesn't